# Rails text_field_tag, input type missing in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, material-design

I'm using materialize with rails 4.2.7, and when i use rails **text_field_tag** the **input type="text"** attribute is not available in the production environment, whereas it is available in the developement env

```
<div class="input-field col l6 m6 s12 clear-margin">
   <%= text_field_tag :address,"", :class => "location-field", id: 
   "address" %>
   <label for="address">Address</label>
</div>
```

The output in development is as follow

```
<input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="" class="location-field" data-parsley-id="6097">
```

But in production the input type attribute is not appearing, can anyone help me with this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by using jquery.

```
if($("input:not([type])").length>0){
  $( "input:not([type])").on('focus',function({$(this).siblings("label").addClass("active")})
  $( "input:not([type])").on('blur',function(){
   if (!$(this).val() ) { 
     $(this).siblings("label").removeClass("active")
   }
 })
}
```